# PHP Array during echo

Tags: php, arrays

I have an assignment to do but am having trouble understanding the given psuedocode :/

```
<?php
$bucket = new array();
print $bucket->addrocks('Rock1')->addrocks('rock2')-
>addrocks('Rock3');

echo "<h1>My Bucket</h1>";
echo "<ul>";
foreach($bucket as $rock){
echo "<li>". $rock ."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
```

Now my trouble starts with understanding how they want me to construct the array after the "print" call? i am not looking for a direct answer to this just maybe a tutorial link or a finger in the right direction

Thank you in advance

Comment: man what you are doing is correct , the problem is that your array is empty and syntax is incorrect , delete new

Comment: `new array()` is that a mistake?

Comment: looks like `$bucket[]='Rock1'; $bucket[]='Rock2'; $bucket[]='Rock3';` to me.

Comment: $bucket->addrocks shall return its same object; Also take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Comment: What exactly is this supposed to do? You are treating $bucket as an object that has a method called addrocks(), but you've created it as an empty array. The rest of the code is fine in that you are creating an unordered list and iterating through each item in $bucket and printing them.

Comment: The word *new* lets me assume that `array` is a class. Classes should start with an uppercase character.

Comment: @MCEmperor i guess it not authorized , array is special word

Comment: Are you going for a Object Array? or a traditional array..?

Comment: @FaceOfJock Hm, that's true. But an array is created like this: `$bucket = array();`. It looks like they're confusing array and object creating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, `new` is only used for instantiating [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) Furthermore, `array` is a [reserved word](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) in PHP, so name your class something else. To instantiate an array in PHP you do this:

```
 $my_array = array();
```

Now to add items to the array you would do this:

```
 $my_array[] = "Rock 1";
 $my_array[] = "Rock 2";
 $my_array[] = "Rock 3";
```

To traverse the array you can use any type of loop, but usually you would just use a `foreach` loop.

For example:

```
 foreach($my_array as $key => $value) {
   echo $value . "<br />";
 }
```

Comment: You did not use `new` keyword also.

Comment: @Starx when trying this , class array { } it's not working array is special word ,this can't be done

Comment: Have you stopped to think, maybe he was going for a STD Array class?

Comment: @FaceOfJock, No I am responding to his comment about `Wrong. you do not use new` in the other answer by Joren.

Comment: @DarylGill, How do you instantiate a STD Array class?

Comment: @Starx I still don't understand your response.

Comment: @RPM, Why did you say the answer by Joren `wrong` stating he has not used `new`? You haven't used it either. Do you understand now?

Comment: @Starx. If you look at the edit log you can see that his first version of the answer included the word `new` to the left of the `array()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the array construction. This is how one constructs an array in PHP:

**one by one:**

```
$bucket = array();
$bucket[] = "Rock1";
$bucket[] = "Rock2";
$bucket[] = "Rock3";
```

**All at once:**

```
$bucket = array("Rock1","Rock2","Rock3");
```

The documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1):

Well unlikely but may be the `array` is not an construct but an class in your pseudocode. My assumptions depend on the use of `new` keyword and the user of `->` and `addrocks` which looks like a method.

So, create a class called `array` *(stupid I know)* and get going.

However the user of `foreach($bucket)` also shows that it expects $bucket to be array. So decide wisely :)

May be use a magic method called `__toString()` inside the class and return back the array.

Comment: maybe he has toString that returns array ??